# Understanding weighted linear least square problem

Tags: approximation

I am having difficulty in understanding about weighted linear least squares.
Could anybody explain me instead of minimizing the residual sum of squares why we need to minimize the weighted sum of squares? Further, I want to know about the term weighted?
Although I have gone through some wiki notes but I am not able to understand.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at a simple problem:
$$ax=c\\
bx=d$$
where '$=$' is meant as an optimization goal, not as exact equality. So we want to find $x$ such that the error of both equalities is minimized in some optimal sense. If you choose a least squares criterion we get the following error function:

$$\epsilon = (ax-c)^2+(bx-d)^2$$

Now we can decide that for some reason the error in the first equation is more important than the error in the second equation, so we can add a weight ($>1$) to the error component of the first equation:

$$\hat{\epsilon} = w^2(ax-c)^2+(bx-d)^2$$

Minimizing $\hat{\epsilon}$ will result in a smaller error for the first equation at the expense of the error of the second equation. This is the basic idea of a weighted least squares error criterion.

If you solve the original (unweighted) problem by solving $\frac{d\epsilon}{dx}=0$ you get the optimal solution:

$$x_o=\frac{ac+bd}{a^2+b^2}$$

If you solve the weighted least squares problem by solving $\frac{d\hat{\epsilon}}{dx}=0$ you get

$$\hat{x}_o=\frac{w^2ac+bd}{w^2a^2+b^2}$$

From this you can see that if the weight $w$ is chosen very large, the solution $\hat{x}_o$ becomes close to $\frac{c}{a}$, which is simply the exact solution of the first equation, not at all considering the second equation. Obvioulsy, by using a weight $w>1$ you give more importance to the first equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have few queries: 1: What is the meaning of the error in the first equation is more important than the error in the second equation. And how adding weight $w$ can help here?

Comment: It simply means that you do not only want to minimize the overall error, but you want to give importance to individual components of the error. If one of the equation errors gets a higher weight, then the resulting error of this specific equation will be smaller than without weighting.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your added detail cleared all to me. :)